# Python: Django comparing timezone.now() with DateTimeField Object

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to validate if the date isn't earlier than the current time. So I've read somewhere in the forums that I should use `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()`

> Django is giving you a timezone-aware datetime object. datetime.now()
> is giving you a timezone-naive datetime object. You can't compare
> these.
>
> Instead use django.utils.timezone.now(), which provides the type of datetime

So basically as a Django developer, I should better use what Django can offer in default. I got these settings in the main settings file:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Vilnius'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

This is my logic for validating the provided date/time:

```
if date <= timezone.now():
    raise serializers.ValidationError("Meeting could not start earlier than the current time")
return date
```

But it always returns the date object instead of raising the `ValidationError`. These are the times which I'm playing with:

```
if timezone.now() < parse(reservation['date_from']):
    raise serializers.ValidationError("Meeting could not start earlier than the current time")
```

!NOTE: I'm using `.parse()` to convert the object from `str` to `datetime` object.

```
timezone.now() returns - 2020-11-22 00:16:55.334792+00:00
reservation['date_from'] returns - 2020-12-04T16:32:00+02:00 
reservation['date_from'] returns - 2020-12-04 16:32:00+02:00
```

Comment: For your second example `reservation['date_from']` < `timezone.now()` so validation passed. 
Maybe you need flip like this `if  parse(reservation['date_from']) < timezone.now()`:

Comment: I changed the `timezone.now()` to `timezone.localtime(timezone.now())` to return UTC3, but it's still failing.

Comment: `2020-11-22 02:56:45.295127+02:00` - server time, request time - `2020-11-22 04:40:00+02:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure you're comparing dates in same timezones you'd better convert them to same timezone. Actually I prefer converting to UTC. As you're using `.parse()` (I assume from dateutil) the resulting datetime value (including timezone, offset etc.) depends on the string it was presented. So, you may convert the resulting datetime into UTC using `.astimezone(pytz.utc)`. And as `django.utils.timezone.now()` returns current time in UTC you may compare them directly. For more info you may print the result of `parse(reservation['date_from']).astimezone(pytz.utc)` to see actual time in UTC.

So I'd offer using comparison in this way:

```
if timezone.now() < parse(reservation['date_from']).astimezone(pytz.utc):
    raise serializers.ValidationError("Meeting could not start earlier than the current time")
```

Comment: Hey, I have finished with this solution if `timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) > date`, but wait, how can I convert the provided time to server local timezone?

Comment: Django provides `django.utils.timezone.get_current_timezone()` function, which returns current active timezone, so you may use `.parse('...').astimezone(get_current_timezone())` and than you should compare to `timezone.localtime(timezone.now())`

Answer (score -1):

Use this in Models.py for setting date automatically :-

```
date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```